# On 18.04 the notification is flashing

Tags: 18.04, notification

Suddenly I have an issue with 18.04 that the notification flashing for a split-second. It goes away so fast that I am not able to see what is triggering the notification OR what is in the text message there. But it is super annoying and distracting. When I am working or looking at other screen the constant flashing of the notification pop up makes it impossible to concentrate.

- Is there a way that I can see past notifications to figure out what is causing the notification ?

I am mostly just using what came out of the box and haven't done many customizations. I do have the tweaks installed though, but not the notification-osd.

I have been using the same config for over 3 months and the problem started happening today.

EDIT: It seems like it is the 'Ubuntu is Ready' notification.

EDIT2: I was wrong earlier. It is a `Connection failed` message.

Answer (score 0):

Well turns out that my laptop was searching for a wired connection all the time after I plugged in an adapter which has an Ethernet port on it. and thats why it was showing the failed to connect notification repeatedly.

I still would like to know how to see all past notifications. I basically started a screen recording and then played it back frame by frame to see what the notification was.